# What do I need to include for java RandomUtils?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse and must not have the right import statements, what do I need to use RandomUtils?

Comment: In eclipse place the cursor on statement which is asking for import. Press Ctrl+1 it will show you all possible import option for that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to

```
 import org.apache.commons.lang.math.RandomUtils;
```

in any class file that uses that class.

You also need to make sure that the Apache Commons jar is in your build path

Answer (score 1):

apache `commons.jar` should be in your classpath.

[RandomUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/math/RandomUtils.html) is not default class with sun java. Download apache commons from apache website and add it your classpath. Then do import.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.jarfinder.com